# How can I find expansion coefficients of the a vector in a given basis?

Tags: homework, self-study, matrix

How can I find the coefficient of the vector $\mathbf y$? And how can the inner product be done on these vectors?

> Let $\mathbf y = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$
>
> What are the expansion coefficients of $\mathbf y$ in the basis $\left\{\mathbf v^{(0)}, \mathbf v^{(1)}, \mathbf v^{(2)}, \mathbf v^{(3)}\right\}$ where
> $$\mathbf v^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf v^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 12\\\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\-\frac 12\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf v^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\\frac 12\\-\frac 12\end{bmatrix}, \mathbf v^{(3)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\-\frac 12\\\frac 12\end{bmatrix}, \quad $$

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a math problem, but it is related to signal processing via the concept of [signal space](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/0470024135.app1). Since it's a homework-style problem you'll only get hints that should help you solve the problem on your own.

1. verify that the given vectors are [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality).
2. if you've convinced yourself that the vectors are orthonormal, you can conclude that the expansion coefficients are simply the inner product of the given vector with the basis vectors, i.e., $$\mathbf{y}=\sum_{i=0}^3(\mathbf{y}\cdot \mathbf{v}^{(i)})\mathbf{v}^{(i)}$$

I don't understand your question about how to compute the inner product. If you know (or look up) the definition of the inner product then you should be able to compute it.